# Coloring the background of a DIV

Tags: css, html

I'm new in CSS so, I hope You can help me plz.

I have a DIV with 3 DIVs inside (left DIV, Center DIV, Right DIV)

I can put the background I want individually (DIV by DIV) but, as they aren't together, there are gaps of color between them. So I tried to put the same backgroud color in the DIV that contains the three but it just doesn't work.

Can You Please Help me?

Thank You Very Much!

The Html

```
<!--Divs-->
<!--<div class="cor_fundo">-->
<div class="body_resize">
  <div class="left">
   left
  left left left left left left left left left  left left left left ddddddddd</div>
  <div class="center">
  center
  ccccccccccccccc</div>
  <div class="right">
  right rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<!--</div>-->
<!--FIM - Divs-->
```

The CSS

```
<!-- Divs Topo Pagina-->
.body_resize  { padding:0; width:740px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#fff} -> this is the one that dont works

.right { width:130px;margin:0; padding:10px; float:right; background-color:#99CCFF}
.center {width:150px;margin:0; padding:10px; float:left; background-color:#99CCFF}
.left {width:400px;margin:0; padding:10px; float:left; background-color:#99CCFF}
<!-- FIM - Divs Topo Pagina-->
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Iuppiter/c8dY8/

Comment: Just a nitpick: Shouldn't be tagged as PHP. There is no PHP here.

Comment: I don't see any gaps http://jsfiddle.net/R7R8W/

Answer (score 0):

I have customized your css a bit.. Please see below

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="body_resize">
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="center">center</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.body_resize  { padding:0; width:740px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#99CCFF; display:table;} 
.right { width:130px;margin:0; padding:10px;display:table-row; float:left; }
.center {width:150px;margin:0; padding:10px;display:table-row ; float:left;}
.left {width:400px;margin:0; padding:10px; display:table-row; float:left; }
```

JsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/6uXwZ/

Comment: Hello! Tkz by the awnser!
But, same problem, the backgrowd color does not change.
Can you help me?

Comment: Why background color is not changing, i have given background color to parent div, just change it from there..

Comment: Yes, as a tried before, but it just don't works. Dont know why... But I Solved the problem by other way! Thank You for Tour Help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.body_resize { padding:0; margin:0 auto; background-color:#99CCFF; }
.right { width:130px;margin:0; padding:10px; float:right; }
.center { width:150px;margin:0; padding:10px; float:left; }
.left { width:400px;margin:0; padding:10px; float:left; }
.clr { clear:both; } /* i think u missed this */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8dY8/2/

Btw, if you want to comment in css files, use `/* ... */` instead of `<!-- ... -->`.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer! But when i access with a cellphone, the only background that has color are the 3 divs inside and not the all region. Can you help me?

Comment: set `background-color` to `body` instead of `.body_resize` then: `body { background-color:#99CCFF; }`

Comment: but if i do that it will set all the background of the page that color. I only want the DIV zone. 
What i want is to do something like this (http://wordpress.dominiodainformatica.com/?page_id=75) but without a table, with divs so it can be responsive. Where is the grey area i want a light blue one.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I just added

> display:table to the class body_resize

**HTML**

```
<div class="body_resize">
  <div class="left">
   left
  left left left left left left left left left  left left left left ddddddddd</div>
  <div class="center">
  center
  ccccccccccccccc</div>
  <div class="right">
  right rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.body_resize  {
    margin:0px auto;
     padding:0;
    width:1000px;
        display:table;
     background-color:black;
}

.right { 
    width:250px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline:block;
    background-color:red;
}
.center {
    width:250px;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    float:left; 
    text-align:center;
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
}
.left {
    width:250px;
    margin:0; 
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    display:inline:block;
    background-color:#99CCFF}
```

Fiddle [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/6pn89/9/)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer! But when i access with a cellphone, the only background that has color are the 3 divs inside and not the all region. Can you help me?

Comment: Hey may i know how you checked it in mobile?

Comment: acessing thru the webpage

Comment: can you add overflow:hidden; to the class body_resize? check it and let me know about it.

Comment: What i want is to do something like this (wordpress.dominiodainformatica.com/?page_id=75) but without using a table, I want to use divs so it can be responsive. Where is the grey area i want a light blue one. Thank You